# Trouble using jquery to remove "»" from element

Tags: jquery, html

I am having trouble using jquery to remove the character "»" from an element. My code is below:

HTML:

```
<div>» <span>something</span></div>
```

Jquery:

```
var v = $j("span").html().replace("»",'');
$j("span").html(v)
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aPBYv/2/

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: because you are looking the html of span try div.

Comment: The » character isn't in the span, replace "span" with "div".

Comment: I think you were blinded by the fact that the character was »

Answer (score 1):

The `»` character is inside `div` not `span`.

If you search inside div, your code works:

**Jquery**

```
var v = $j("div").html().replace("»",'');
$j("div").html(v)
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aPBYv/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
var v = $('div').html().replace("»",'');
$('div').html(v);
```